# EF - Linq to Entity and navigation property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need design a simple LINQ to Entity query using EF. I am pretty new at it and I am stuck for more of 1 day.

From my DataBase table are:

```
CmsJobs
CmsJobsContents (Pure Junctional Table)
CmsContents
```

**I need list a series of CmsContents with a specific CmsJobs.JobId**

Any idea how to do it?
Thanks for your help

My Model EF:

[image]

Comment: Singulariz your entity names would be a good thing to do imho.

Comment: And obviously when you are this (see question) new to EF :P reading a good book won't harm you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CmsJob job = (from j in dataContext.CmsJobs where j.JobId == jobIdIAmLookingFor select j).FirstOrDefault();   
IEnumerable<CmsContent> theContentItems = job.CmsContents;
```

Comment: HI, i receive an error Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<WebProject.DataAccess.DatabaseModels.CmsJob>' to 'WebProject.DataAccess.DatabaseModels.CmsJob'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Updated the answer. It was complaining that the first query could potentially return multiple jobs (the compiler doesn't know that there will (hopefully) only be one job with a given identifier). Adding the .FirstOrDefault() makes the query return the first matching job or null if no such job exists.

Comment: Thanks Rune, now it is works! :-) Just a question is your code LINQ to Entity or are you also using Query builder methods? thanks once again

Comment: hi, what about this int findJobId = 58; CmsJob findJob = context.CmsJobs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.JobId == findJobId); IEnumerable<CmsContent> resultContents = findJob.CmsContents;

Answer (score 1):

Or more readible and **faster** (I recently did a lot of tests to query the model from one way or the other (fromout a CmsJobs perspective or fromout the CmsContents perspective):

```
    using(EntityModel context = new EntityModel())
    {
      List<CmsContents> list = context.CmsContents
                               .Include("CmsJobs")
                               .Where<CmsContents>(cc => cc.CmsJobs.Where<CmsJobs>(cj => cj.JobId == requiredId))
                               .ToList<CmsContents>()
    }
```

Did not test this, but should work I believe. Try it out yourself. It's the less logical way of querying perspective but gives you **exactly** what you need (a list of CmsContents entities) without the containing CmsJobs entity (as supposed by Rune).

Comment: Just a note: you don't *need* the `<CmsContents>` in the `Where()` and `ToList()` methods, but it does make it more clear what they are returning.

Comment: hi, thanks joep i will test it, did you use linq or Query builder methods? thanks

Comment: @Hans Kesting: I know but as you already mentioned it makes it more readable. @GIbbok: hmmm...Linq To Entities isn't it?

Comment: hi, what about this                 int findJobId = 58;
                CmsJob findJob = context.CmsJobs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.JobId == findJobId);
                IEnumerable<CmsContent> resultContents = findJob.CmsContents;

Comment: @GIbbok: looks good. Do you see the different query approach? You query from the Job perspective as I queried from the Content perspective. This might have effects on performance as I mentioned earlier (based on table size of both tables, etc.). Also, you now have a Job entity in memory, do you really need that? When you really only need the Content entities consider using my approach.

Comment: Joep thanks, I now understand your point. I am rally beginners in programming so I have to learn alot :-). May I ask you how are you able to measure the performance of a query. So I can compare the two approches. Sql Profiler? Or any other tool? Thanks once again for your time.!

Comment: @GIbbok: I simple measured it in a console program with an Entity Datamodel attached to it. Take your alternative approaches of querying the model, execute them 100, 1000 times divide the total time by the number of iterations and voila! Also, with Anjlib SQl Profiler I look at the generated SQL by EF to gain some more understanding. Another question: are you going to accept this as an answer? I'm a bit tensed because I spent a lot of effort in answering questions of people which don't mind about accepting an answer or upvoting answers, you see?

Comment: @GIbbok: Provide enough dummy data for a realistic test scenario. testing against a database with 10 records won't point out any big differences probably.

Comment: Thanks Joep for your help and reply, offcourse I voted your answer :-) have a nice day